# Can I use #undef and #define mid code to change something in another function?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define TYPE char
typedef struct node
{
    TYPE data;
    struct node *next;
} node;
typedef struct
{
    node *top;
} stack;
node *newNode(TYPE x)
{
    node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->data = x;
    n->next = NULL;
    return n;
}
```

Can I later change the type to a `float` in another function and, if so, how do I do that? I am trying to use my stack as another thing or do I have to write another separate set of functions?

Comment: No, you can't. The preprocessor is just simple text substitution, and it processes the file in order at compile time. Redefining a macro has no effect on earlier uses.

Comment: Think of the pre-processor as an editor. When you say `#define FOO`, you're giving a substitution that should be carried out for all `FOO`s in the  _text_ that follows until an optional `#undef FOO`.  From that point forward `FOO` isn't substituted any more unless there's a later `#define`. The point is that it's all about _text_.

Comment: No. But you could use a `union` instead of `TYPE data;`. (e.g.) `union { int data_int; double data_double; };`

Comment: you can `#undef` TYPE and `#define` it again as something different. But it won't change whats already been compiled

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to emulate C++ templates. C doesn't have a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, this is because macro's are pre-processed what you can do is either use a union(not the best) or allocate dynamic memory (bytes) and then append them and cast them to form the variable you want, there's also void pointers etc...

For example with the void pointers you could do something like
they allow your nodes to have different types of data although it can be hard to manage it as you start to have strings, etc...

```c
{
    void * datapnt;
    struct node *next;
} node;
...
//on main or another place
type* t = malloc(...); 
t[0]=some value;
node->datapnt=t;
//now data points to its value
```